# Multiple loops in ansible task

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm trying to use vars to perform loops in ansible but I'm struggling to get them to work. The documentation talks about the `loop` attribute but as far as I can tell, this only works if you have one loop in a task.

Is it possible to use different loops in a task or must it be split into different tasks?

```
- name: "Configure ufw"
      ufw:
        policy: "{{ defaults.policy }}"
        direction: "{{ defaults.direction }}"
        rule: allow
        src: "{{ rules }}"
        logging: on
        state: enabled
      vars:
        defaults:
          - { direction: incoming, policy: deny }
          - { direction: outgoing, policy: allow }
        rules:
          - 80/tcp
          - 443/tcp
```

When I run the code I get the error

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'direction'

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `with_nested`.  This:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  connection: local

  vars:
    defaults:
      - { direction: incoming, policy: deny }
      - { direction: outgoing, policy: allow }
    rules:
      - 80/tcp
      - 443/tcp

  tasks:
    - name: Change connect file to bulk mode
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.direction }}: {{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
          - "{{ defaults }}"
          - "{{ rules }}"
```

Gives this output:

```
TASK [Change connect file to bulk mode] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "incoming: 80/tcp"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "incoming: 443/tcp"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "outgoing: 80/tcp"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "outgoing: 443/tcp"
}
```

Comment: ...although note that with recent ansible (2.7 and later, I think), the `with_*` constructs are deprecated in favor of the the `loop` construct. The docs show [how to convert from the old style to the new style](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian).

Comment: with_* is not yet deprecated, although it's clear there's a desire to do so.
"We added loop in Ansible 2.5. It is not yet a full replacement for with_<lookup>, but we recommend it for most use cases.
We have not deprecated the use of with_<lookup> - that syntax will still be valid for the foreseeable future."  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#complex-loops

Answer (score 0):

`with_nested` may be an option, as per Jack's answer.

Alternately, and possibly the currently preferred mechanism, is to use `loop: "{{ your_first_list | product (your_second_list) | list }}"` to combine your multiple lists into a single list.

For example, this:

```
- name: test
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.0 }} - {{ item.0.1}} - {{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ [ ['incoming','deny'], ['outgoing','allow']] | product( [ '80/tcp', '443/tcp' ] ) | list }}"
```

produces this output:

```
ok: [examplehost.my.example.com] => (item=[[u'incoming', u'deny'], u'80/tcp']) => {
    "msg": "incoming - deny - 80/tcp"
}
ok: [examplehost.my.example.com] => (item=[[u'incoming', u'deny'], u'443/tcp']) => {
    "msg": "incoming - deny - 443/tcp"
}
ok: [examplehost.my.example.com] => (item=[[u'outgoing', u'allow'], u'80/tcp']) => {
    "msg": "outgoing - allow - 80/tcp"
}
ok: [examplehost.my.example.com] => (item=[[u'outgoing', u'allow'], u'443/tcp']) => {
    "msg": "outgoing - allow - 443/tcp"
}
```